# Excel insert a value one cell down

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a condition statement and when it is true, I would like to insert text or any value one cell/row down. How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking how to insert text or value into a spreadsheet? Presumably you know how to do that -- so what is your actual question?

Comment: I am asking if I can use a formula to insert text into a certain cell. Like is there a fucntion like +INSERTTEXT("The Text", A1)

Comment: Just set the value of a cell to your text - `Cells(1,1).Value = "The Text"`

Answer (score 1):

To insert a row below the active cell:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
```

It's a vague answer for a vague question

Answer (score 0):

A formula cannot effect the value in another cell.

For a conditional statement in A1 to effect B1 you would need to do something like this.  Or use a macro.

```
A1 = if(condition=TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)
B1 = if(A1,put your value here,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I came up with a solution. I just compared the data one row up like so

=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(I1),ISNUMBER(J1)),"-","+")

inorder to  insert the value one row down.

The formula starts at L2 so I just start comparing one row up.